# Disable dates dynamically in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

In my current project, when the user select a hotel, and when he select the arrival date, and departure date, I have to show the hotel unavailable dates as disabled in jquery datepicker

This is my javascript code

```
    $("#select_villa").change(function(){
        $('#textfield1').datepicker( "destroy" );                                          
        var dataString = 'villa=' + $("#select_villa").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "include/getdate.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){


                $('#textfield1').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',                                             
                    minDate: data[0].unavailable_date_from,
                    maxDate: data[0].unavailable_date_to
                });

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Here I have to disable the minDate and maxDate dynamically according to the database availability dates.

This is the result I get when the combobox value changes

```
[{"unavailable_date_from":"2011-03-03","unavailable_date_to":"2011-03-31"}]
```

This is my php ajax snippet to get un-available dates

```
<?php 
include("db.php");
$returnArray = array();
$villa = $_GET['villa'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT unavailable_date_from, unavailable_date_to FROM villa WHERE name = '".$villa."'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)){
        $returnArray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($returnArray);?>
```

Can anybody tell me how can I achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can change the options (such as `minDate` and `maxDate`) using the [`option` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#methods):

```
$('#textfield1').datepicker('option', {
    minDate: newMinDate,
    maxDate: newMaxDate
});
```

So, in your AJAX success handler, just pull the new dates out of `data[0].unavailable_date_from` and `data[0].unavailable_date_to` and send them to the appropriate datepickers as above.

Comment: I tried, but when I change my code like this, the datepicker isn't working :(

Comment: thanks for ur answer, I removed the 'option' and tried, it works fine,but one thing I wanna do, I wanna set the resulted dates disabled and the rest of the dates enabled, is there a way that I could do it, thanks

Comment: @Mujahid: Without the 'option' you're creating a whole new datepicker rather than just updating the options on an existing one. Did you have the datepicker already bound before `$('#textfield1').datepicker('option', ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable specific days, you can do it with the onSelect option for the datepicker.

for example:

```
$('#textfield1').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',                                             
   minDate: data[0].unavailable_date_from,
   maxDate: data[0].unavailable_date_to
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
       if ($.inArray(dateText, data[0].unavailable_dates))
       {
           alert('invalid date');
           // do whatever you like here
       }
   });  

}
```

PS I have made assumptions about your returned data, but think you can see what I'm getting at there. Also make sure that your date formats match from php to the date picker. Otherwise you'll need to convert to Date datatypes in javascript.